I am trying to get a certain response from this code in common lisp but not getting required result, if somebody can help on this
While trying to get a particular response with the code below, i am not getting that.
I am getting this as an output:
{"name": Bull,"age": 30,"city": Nowhere}

The output i want:
{"name": "John","age": "30","city": "Nowhere"}

Below is the code snippet:
(defun create-json-object (key value)
  (format nil "\"~a\": ~a" key value))

(defun example-json-encode ()
  (let ((name "Bull")
        (age 30)
        (city "Nowhere"))
    (let ((json-object (list (create-json-object "name" name)
                             (create-json-object "age" age)
                             (create-json-object "city" city))))
      (format t "{~{~a~^,~}}"  json-object))))
(print(example-json-encode))

I tried to do something like this, but getting warning while compiling and not getting the desired output in input-msg
(defun create-json-object (key value)
  (format nil "~s: ~s" key value))
 
(defun json-encode ()
  (let ((requestID "DUMMYREQUEST")
        (sId "OL")
        (city "RANCHI")
        (houseNumber 12345)
        (streetName "MG ROAD")
        (state "JH")
        (QType "HIGH")
        (POBOX nil)
        (input-msg nil)
        (Network "OWN")
        (MessageSrcSystem "XXXX"))
 
            (let ((input-msg (create-json-record requestID sId city houseNumber streetName state QType POBOX Network MessageSrcSystem)))
                (format t "~a" input-msg))))
 
 
(defun create-json-record (requestID sId city houseNumber streetName state QType POBOX Network MessageSrcSystem)
   (let ((json-object (list (create-json-object "requestId" requestID)
                            (create-json-object "sId" sId)
                            (create-json-object "houseNumber" houseNumber)
                            (create-json-object "streetName" streetName)
                            (create-json-object "city" city)
                            (create-json-object "state" state)
                            (create-json-object "quality" QType)
                            (create-json-object "postoffice" POBOX)
                            (create-json-object "network" Network)
                            (create-json-object "messageSrcSystem" MessageSrcSystem))))
                       (format nil "{~{~a~^,~}}" json-object)))

Listener output:
;;; Compiling file /home/telly/test3.lisp ...
;;; Safety = 3, Speed = 1, Space = 1, Float = 1, Interruptible = 1
;;; Compilation speed = 1, Debug = 2, Fixnum safety = 3
;;; Source level debugging is on
;;; Source file recording is  on
;;; Cross referencing is on
; (TOP-LEVEL-FORM 0)
; CREATE-JSON-OBJECT
;;;*** Warning in JSON-ENCODE: INPUT-MSG is bound but not referenced
; JSON-ENCODE
; CREATE-JSON-RECORD


Use an existing json library instead of trying to do it yourself. https://sabracrolleton.github.io/json-review has a list with a ton of notes and comparisons to help pick the best one for your needs.

You want to print the name and city strings so that the results can be read as strings. The ~A format directive is intended for printing results that look good to humans. The ~S directive is intended for printing results that can be read by the lisp reader, so it will print the quotes.
Change create-json-object to this:
(defun create-json-object (key value)
  (format nil "~s: ~s" key value))

Also, you can return a string from example-json-decode. format outputs to *standard-output* when the stream is specified as t, but it outputs to a string if the supplied stream is nil.
(defun example-json-encode ()
  (let ((name "John")
        (age 30)
        (city "Nowhere"))
    (let ((json-object (list (create-json-object "name" name)
                             (create-json-object "age" age)
                             (create-json-object "city" city))))
      (format nil "{~{~a~^,~}}"  json-object))))

Finally, print and prin1 are intended for printing objects that can be read by the lisp reader. You should use princ or format with suitable directives to print objects for human consumption.
CL-USER> (princ (example-json-encode))
{"name": "John","age": 30,"city": "Nowhere"}
"{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}" ; return value from `princ`

CL-USER> (format t "~a" (example-json-encode))
{"name": "John","age": 30,"city": "Nowhere"}
NIL                                                      ; return value from `format`

It might be convenient to create a function that creates a json person from some input, e.g.:
(defun create-json-person (name age city)
  (let ((json-object (list (create-json-object "name" name)
                           (create-json-object "age" age)
                           (create-json-object "city" city))))
    (format nil "{~{~a~^,~}}"  json-object)))

Then you can easily create json people:
CL-USER> (create-json-person "John" 30 "Nowhere")
"{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}"

CL-USER> (let ((jp (create-json-person "John" 30 "Nowhere")))
           (format t "~a" jp))
{"name": "John","age": 30,"city": "Nowhere"}
NIL

CL-USER> (let ((names '("John" "Cindy" "Santa Claus"))
               (ages '(30 32 Unknown))
               (cities '("Nowhere" "Whoville" "The North Pole")))
           (mapcar #'create-json-person names ages cities))
("{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}"
 "{\"name\": \"Cindy\",\"age\": 32,\"city\": \"Whoville\"}"
 "{\"name\": \"Santa Claus\",\"age\": UNKNOWN,\"city\": \"The North Pole\"}")

CL-USER> (let* ((names '("John" "Cindy" "Santa Claus"))
                (ages '(30 32 Unknown))
                (cities '("Nowhere" "Whoville" "The North Pole"))
                (persons (mapcar #'create-json-person names ages cities)))
           (dolist (person persons)
             (format t "~%~a" person)))

{"name": "John","age": 30,"city": "Nowhere"}
{"name": "Cindy","age": 32,"city": "Whoville"}
{"name": "Santa Claus","age": UNKNOWN,"city": "The North Pole"}
NIL

OP Updated Question
The OP has updated the original question with new json-encode and create-json-record functions. When this code is compiled OP gets a warning about an unused input-msg variable.
There are two of these input-msg variables in the json-encode function: one in the outer let scope, and one in the inner let scope. The one in the outer scope serves no purpose, and should just be removed. Further, unless OP intends to do further work with input-msg inside the body of the inner let form, this variable also serves no purpose. In fact, it looks like the entire json-encode function serves no purpose. It only serves to call create-json-record, but it would be just as well to call create-json-record directly.
This and the previous OP question about how to "put the output in a variable" have led me to wonder if OP has some misconceptions about how variables work in Common Lisp.
There are four obvious things that you can do with the result of create-json-record. You can use the result directly in some other expression, you can bind the result to a local variable (in a let form), you can define a global variable which holds the result (a special variable, but let's not get into the details of that here), or you can store the result in a previously defined global variable. Always the goal is to do something with the created json record.
In some other expression:
(do-something-with-json-record (create-json-record requestId ;...))

Binding to a local variable:
(let ((input-msg (create-json-record requestId ;...)))
  ;; possibly some other code
  (do-something-with-json-record input-msg)
  ;; possibly some other code
  )

Defining a global variable:
(defvar *input-msg* (create-json-record requestID ;...))
;; possibly some other code

(do-something-with-json-record *input-msg*)

;; possibly some other code

Binding to a previously defined global variable:
(defvar *input-msg*)

;; possibly some other code

(setf *input-msg* (create-json-record requestID ;...))

;; possibly some other code

(do-something-with-json-record *input-msg*)

;; possibly some other code

A few comments about the last two examples. Here the *input-msg* variable has "earmuffs", i.e., asterisks around the variable name. This is a Common Lisp convention used to indicate that a variable is a special variable (also called a dynamic variable). Special variables behave differently than local variables, and to a first approximation they behave as global variables in other languages. But there are significant differences in their behavior and it is good to know when a variable is special, hence the convention. It is almost certainly the case that you should not be binding json records to a global variable; it just doesn't make much sense. You could use defparameter instead of defvar, but the nuance of why you might choose one over the other is well beyond the scope of this question.
Potential Improvements
The create-json-record function is very specific. This function creates a particular kind of json record, but not general json records. You could write a function that generalizes the process of creating json records which is not tied to a particular record type, for example:
(defun make-json-record (&rest k-v-list)
  (format nil "{~{~a~^,~}}"
          (loop for (k v) on k-v-list by #'cddr
                collecting (create-json-object k v))))

When you call this function with keys and associated values you get back a json record:
CL-USER> (make-json-record "requestID" "DUMMYREQUEST"
                           "sId" "OL"
                           "city" "RANCHI"
                           "houseNumber" 12345
                           "streetName" "MG ROAD"
                           "state" "JH"
                           "QType" "HIGH"
                           "POBOX" nil
                           "Network" "OWN"
                           "MessageSrcSystem" "XXXX")
"{\"requestID\": \"DUMMYREQUEST\",\"sId\": \"OL\",\"city\": \"RANCHI\",\"houseNumber\": 12345,\"streetName\": \"MG ROAD\",\"state\": \"JH\",\"QType\": \"HIGH\",\"POBOX\": NIL,\"Network\": \"OWN\",\"MessageSrcSystem\": \"XXXX\"}"

You could use this more general make-json-record to create more specific functions:
(defun create-json-person (name age city)
  (make-json-record "name" name
                    "age" age
                    "city" city))

This can be used to create json-person records:
CL-USER> (create-json-person "John" 30 "Nowhere")
"{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}"

Escaping Confusion
OP seems to think that the above functions create data in the wrong format:

i mean, if there would not have "\" in the output, it would have been great

OP has sought to "put the output into a variable." I think that there is some confusion here. A string created by create-json-person does not include extra backslashes, but these occur in the printed representation of the string. This is distinct from the string object itself. Consider:
CL-USER> (let ((json (create-json-person "John" 30 "Nowhere")))
           (format t "Printed representation of the string:~%~S~%" json)
           (format t "~%Printing the string:~%~A~%~%" json)
           (format t "~%List of character literals in the string:~%~S~%"
                   (coerce json 'list))
           (format t "~%List of characters in the string:~%~A~%"
                   (coerce json 'list)))
Printed representation of the string:
"{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}"

Printing the string:
{"name": "John","age": 30,"city": "Nowhere"}

List of character literals in the string:
(#\{ #\" #\n #\a #\m #\e #\" #\: #\  #\" #\J #\o #\h #\n #\" #\, #\" #\a #\g
 #\e #\" #\: #\  #\3 #\0 #\, #\" #\c #\i #\t #\y #\" #\: #\  #\" #\N #\o #\w
 #\h #\e #\r #\e #\" #\})

List of characters in the string:
({ " n a m e " :   " J o h n " , " a g e " :   3 0 , " c i t y " :   " N o w h
 e r e " })
NIL

The escape backslashes only show up when viewing the printed representation of the json string. When the string is printed the escape characters disappear. It is convenient to work with json encoded as strings, but if you are trying to use these json strings to work with some API you may need to encode the json in a different form. One thing that you can do is encode the json string as a vector of octets. The code below uses the implementation-specific function string-to-octets provided by SBCL, but other implementations provide similar functionality, and of course there are libraries available that can also do this.
CL-USER> (let* ((json (create-json-person "John" 30 "Nowhere"))
                (json-octets (sb-ext:string-to-octets json)))
           (format t "Printed representation of the string:~%~S~%" json)
           (format t "~%Octets of the string:~%~A~%" json-octets))
Printed representation of the string:
"{\"name\": \"John\",\"age\": 30,\"city\": \"Nowhere\"}"

Octets of the string:
#(123 34 110 97 109 101 34 58 32 34 74 111 104 110 34 44 34 97 103 101 34 58 32
  51 48 44 34 99 105 116 121 34 58 32 34 78 111 119 104 101 114 101 34 125)
NIL

The bottom line is that OP must identify their requirements. Either OP is writing the code that will handle json data, or OP will use some library functions for this. The formatting and encoding needs of this code is unknown until OP decides what is to be done. But, the original question was about printing strings containing quotes. That question and much more has been answered.

Thank you, is there any way i can put the output into a variable

Sure. format returns a string when used with a nil destination, and you can store that in a variable. I added some more examples.

please, have a look above tried that but input-msg not getting set to the output

I don't understand your comment. In the json-encode function of the new code that you posted there are two input-msg variables: one in the outer let scope and one in the inner let scope. The first one is never used, and the second one shadows the first. Try this: (let ((x 42))  (let ((x "I am shadowing the outer X"))  (princ x))). Here the outer x serves no purpose, just like the outer input-msg in your program. This is what the warning is about. Just remove the input-msg binding from the outer let form.

Beyond that, the posted code seems to work as intended. Unless your intent is to somehow save the output from the inner let form in the input-msg of the outer form. That isn't how let-bound variables work, though. I will add to my answer, but this question seems to have gone beyond the scope of the original question.

i have removed input-msg from outer let. this is what i tried, but do not see the output being set to input-data. When i use setf for input-msg, the output comes but not in the desired format, i mean, if there would not have "" in the output, it would have been great

In your posted code the output is set to input-msg inside the innermost let form, and only there. That variable is not visible anywhere else. "...not in the desired format...." The backslashes are escape characters which are needed to escape the double quotes inside of strings.

I think that you have some confusion around the difference between the values of data and their printed representations. I have tried one last time to clarify this in my answer.
